# Unable to return bool after catch

Tags: c#

I am trying to return the value `false` if an exception is caught in a method, but instead, it seems to return an exception rather than the bool.

I use this to call the first method:

```
try
{
    bool wasImported = WriteAddress(theCompany.CompanyId, company);
    if(wasImported == false)
    {
        ///some logic here
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    string msg = ex.Message;
}
```

Here is the `WriteAddress` method:

```
private bool WriteAddress(Guid companyId, ModuleView.CompanyBO company)
{
    try
    {
        if (company.First_Address != "" || company.First_Address2 != "" || company.First_City != "" || company.First_State != "" || company.First_Zip != "")
        {
            bool isDate = false; 
            DateTime thisDate;
            ModuleView.AddressBO theAddress = new ModuleView.AddressBO();
            theAddress.CompanyId = companyId;
            // theAddress.Address = Conversions.Truncate(company.First_Address,200);
            theAddress.Address = company.First_Address;
            theAddress.Address2 = Conversions.Truncate(company.First_Address2,200);
            theAddress.City = Conversions.Truncate(company.First_City,50);
            theAddress.State = Conversions.Truncate(company.First_State,100);
            theAddress.Zip = Conversions.Truncate(company.First_Zip,50);
            theAddress.Country = Conversions.Truncate(company.First_Country,150);
            theAddress.Phone = Conversions.Truncate(company.First_Phone,30);
            theAddress.Fax = Conversions.Truncate(company.First_Fax,30);
            theAddress.AddressId = CompanyBA.Address_Insert(DB_Context, theAddress);
            if(theAddress.AddressId == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the `Address_Insert` method:

```
public static void Address_Insert(COG_ContextDB context, COGS.DomainDataModel.Address item)
{
    context.Addresses.Add(item);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I am purposely not truncating the Address field in order to produce an error when the method `CompanyBA.Address_Insert(DB_Context, theAddress);` is called.  That method returns an error which triggers the `catch` block.  The `catch` block has `return false`, but instead of returning `false`, and executing the `if(wasImported == false)` in the calling method, it returns an error and the first catch block executes.  Is there anyway to get the `WriteAddress` method to return `false` instead of executing the `catch` block in the calling method?  I hope I am explaining this correctly.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: "Thread was being aborted" I believe is the message.  I am running again to be sure.

Comment: Then you have to look somewhere else. Is this code running in a thread? -- That was aborted?

Comment: Not really using threading.  I am adding the insert code to see if that helps.

Comment: [ThreadAbortException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadabortexception?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) can't be swallowed. If it's not rethrown at the end of a `catch`, the runtime does it automatically.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: You don't actually show the code you are using. Your Address_Insert in the questions returns void, but in the code you assign its return value to a variable.

Comment: As a side-note: Why would you even want to have the WriteAddress method return a boolean value? If it goes wrong unexpectedly, have the exception bubble up the call stack to a place where you want to handle errors.

Comment: @NineBerry - Because if the address does not write, I am required to remove the already added associated company record for that address.

Comment: @NineBerry.  It returns a Guid.  I just did not include both insert methods.  I do not write the data methods.

Comment: The final step when producing a minimal reproducible example is to make a new project, paste your code in, and verify that it reproduces your issue.  If you did not include the insert methods, delete them from your code and see if the problem goes away.  If it does, you can exclude them from your example.  If it doesn't, you must include them in your example.  If you cannot do so, then you're in a position where there is a bug in code that you cannot debug...so you shouldn't ask us to do it, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am trying to return the value false if an exception is caught in a method, but instead, it seems to return an Exception rather than the bool.

That is very unusual, but fortunately you gave the clue in a comment:

> "Thread was being aborted" I believe is the message.

If you could catch a thread abort exception and turn it into a return then the thread would never abort!  A thread abort exception can be caught but it is automatically re-thrown so that the thread does in fact abort. (Aside: there *are* ways to prevent or delay an aborted thread from aborting; you must not *rely* on thread aborting to abort a thread in a timely manner for program correctness.)

That said:  **Aborting a thread is a worst practice in C# and you should not do so**. Since you will now never abort a thread, you will never need to worry about catching a thread abort exception and have to deal with its unusual behaviour.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff: Well, you have a mystery to solve then, because if you're getting a thread abort exception, someone is aborting a thread. Get busy figuring that one out!

Comment: Unfortunately, I searched the entire solution just now, and it does not seem that Abort() is being called anywhere in the project by any developer code.  I will tell you that when I finally did get an error that made it sense  (after attempting to update a record in the second catch block).  It was an error regarding the length of the address field which is what caused the initial error.  Really strange.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff As others have pointed out in the comments above, we need a [repro] to be able to form a better idea of what's going on. At least include the [full exception details](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/) _with the stack trace_ in your question.

Comment: Okay, I have figured out why the thread is being aborted.  There is a RedirectToErrorPage in the Insert method.  The Redirect causes the thread abort.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed  I will try to post the full exception details.  This is a webforms application using Entity Framework with SQL database.  I am not sure how to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff: There's no point in producing a reproducer if your question has been answered. Your question was, as I understand it, why the exception is not being caught properly. Now you know; thread abort exceptions cannot be caught permanently. If you cannot avoid the thread being aborted then you are just going to have to live with this. Did that not answer your question? If not, the question could use some clarifying.

Comment: @EricLippert - thank you very much for your time and assistance.